# We need a way to search only for questions or answers

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, search

Just a quick questions:

1. Why can we not search just for questions or just for answers?
2. Will this be a future option?

I think it may be useful for people, especially when they are looking for specific searches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When searching, add the term `is:question` or `is:answer` (or the shorthand `is:q` or `is:a`) to search only for one of the other.

You can read about other useful search operators [on the appropriate Help page.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: You can view this and other advanced features under the link "Advanced Search Tips" on the search results page.